# Images fail to load on my website on IE only

Tags: image, internet-explorer, loading

I just created a website ( http://www.kalif.ca ) for my business.

When I load the site in IE (in my specific case IE 8 on Win 7), on the main page, the only image that's loaded is the logo.

Any insights as to what might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to me that getclicky and crazyegg javascript are slowing your site down but the main thing that sticks out is that you are giving your URL's full paths e.g. http://kalif.ca/media/images/excavator.png and the http://kalif.ca isn't working correctly and taking a long time to redirect to www.kalif.ca and thus show the image. If you insist on full paths please update them to www.kalif.ca.

Comment: Wow, the site is extremely slow in IE! It loads pretty fast on Safari and Chrome. I'll have to chop crazyegg and maybe even clicky.

As for your suggestion to replace kalif.ca with www.kalif.ca. Totally worked! Thanks so much! I wish I could your answer*10 :).

Comment: +1 Not sure whether the full paths are the root of the problem, but the site is loading awfully slowly and with lots of timed-out connections, even with JavaScript turned off.

Comment: @Pekka - if you have firebug - change the path of one of the images and try it and they load instantly

Comment: @Paul yup, that indeed did the trick, it's lightning fast now.

Comment: So the javascript was not causing it to be slow?!

Comment: @Pigrim I don't think so! At least not in regards to the images loading up. They can slow down page loading as a whole, though, if their servers are slow to respond.

Comment: it looks like the redirect to www version of the site was slowing it down not the javascript